# TPD8S009 ESD port nomenclature matter

Tags: pcb, esd, displayport

I'm designing with a TPD8S009 part, and I'm not strictly following the D0+, D0- array stated on the chip. I'm connecting it as shown in the below snapshot. Is this okay? The datasheet simplified schematic makes it seem like there is no difference between the ports and the ESD protection.

Thanks for any tips.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. You can connect it this way, the internal structure is similar on the 8 channels.
Why do you use a 8-channel device? A 4-channel like [HSP061-4M10](https://www.st.com/en/protections-and-emi-filters/hsp061-4m10.html) looks to be enough if you don't need to protect the VCC.

You have to be careful on the layout of the ESD device : close to the connector, minimize the ground path etc... Everything explained here : [AN5686](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group1/c1/5f/ce/0a/48/fc/40/a4/DM00803104/files/DM00803104.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00803104.pdf)

Cheers